# cron script not running with root crontab

Tags: linux, cron, debian

I am testing a cron script in my server (Debian 12). Testing a very simple test script that echo a line in a file:

If I use `crontab -e`, scripts runs fine with my user. The actual script will need to run as root though, so I tried to install the test script it with `sudo crontab -e`. In this case, the script never runs.
I tried also to put the scripts in `/etc/cron.d`, still not working. Tried also with `sudo crontab -e -u root`, not working. No errors, no logs in `/var/log`.

The only logs that I have found are on the journal, but they're pretty useless:

```
Jan 26 09:45:01 server-1 cron[607]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)
Jan 26 09:45:01 server-1 CRON[15437]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jan 26 09:45:01 server-1 CRON[15441]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash -c "/tmp/test.sh")
Jan 26 09:45:01 server-1 CRON[15439]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jan 26 09:45:01 server-1 CRON[15439]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: Since there's no MTA installed and the output is being discarded, and you are not getting the error messages in the email.

Comment: yeah well I do not care about having error messages in the mail. I never asked for that and I do not know why I get  that MTA log. But it is just an info, not error. I would be much happier to figure out what's going on, maybe having a log in /var/log/syslog. But there is noting in /var/log related to the cron or sys

Comment: If the script produces any output, `cron` tries to send it as email. The reason why the script isn't working is likely in that output.

Comment: If you don't want to set up an MTA, redirect stdout and stderr to a file. `/bin/bash -c "/tmp/test.sh" > ~/testout.txt 2>&1`

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: My guess: your script makes assumptions about paths and `PATH` that are incorrect for root. Debug as per @Barmar redirect suggestion

Comment: Putting > ~/testout.txt 2>&1 finally created the log files so I could see what was going on. And indeed it was a PATH problem, the executable could not be found by the root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `> /tmp/test.log 2>&1` to the cron script, it is possible to print the script output in a file.

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -c "/tmp/test.sh" > /tmp/test.log 2>&1
```

This makes much easier to debug it. In this case it was that the root user could not find the executable since it was not in `PATH`.